# Is there any solution to fix this Cors error?

Tags: python, reactjs, django, web, django-cors-headers

I have made an api from django but when I call from my react app It gives CORS error

my settings.py

> INSTALLED_APPS = [
> 'django.contrib.admin',
> 'django.contrib.auth',
> 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
> 'django.contrib.sessions',
> 'django.contrib.messages',
> 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
> 'api.apps.ApiConfig',
> 'rest_framework',
> 'corsheaders', ]
>
> MIDDLEWARE = [
> 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
> 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', ]
>
> CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
> "http://localhost:3000",
> "http://127.0.0.1:3000", ]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyCO5.png)

Comment: you should add a cors middleware to your backend and specify the frontend endpoint as a whitelist, take a look at this, hopefully you could find the way: https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/django-cors-guide/

Comment: Please paste the error message as text in the question, instead of providing a screen capture.

Comment: Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/notes' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Appropriate settings for Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) looks like so:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "...",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",  
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "...",
]
```

To specify which origins you wanna give access to:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://localhost:8000",
)

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["http://localhost:3000"]
```